# Questions regarding Pi calculating program

Tags: c#

I am interested in writing a program that calculates the value of Pi to infinite decimal places. Its something I'm just looking to do to pass time, and have something to work on. So, regarding that, I have a couple of questions:

1. Benchmarking softwares that calculate Pi, what system do they use? Do they use an infinite function that converges towards the value if pi with every passing iteration? If so, what is the best function?
2. What would be the best approach to store the calculated value in a variable? Obviously, no existing data type will be able to hold that amount of information so how do I tackle that?

Comment: You obviously tried some googling before asking that.

Comment: lol....i did. I agree I didn't spend adequate time, but I did google first! I found a few functions that all converge to the value of Pi, but I'm just wondering which would be the best to implement in a program. Regarding the data type, I found nothing.

Comment: Posted what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its for the challenge try building your own datastructure using a list of ArrayLists and maybe just for fun / challenge / really long numbers add virtualization (= storing unused parts of the number to disk).

Sounds like fun :)

Answer (score 1):

See [Viete's forumla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula).  Wikipedia also has a PHP example implementation near the bottom of [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_approximations_of_%CF%80#Development_of_efficient_formulae).

Comment: thanks. I'll look into it. The greater of the challenges for me seems to be storing the value? Any suggestions?

Comment: With this formula I don't think you have to store the number in memory to calculate the next part.

Answer (score 0):

As far as an arbitrary precision .Net library goes, I've heard good things about [W3b.sine](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=sine)